# Importing library Utils

Tags: python, image-classification

I am working on image classification and using Google colab for this purpose.
But when I want to import the following modules, it throws an error.

```
from utils import show_test_cases, test_case_checker, perform_computation

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-ff42356cc1b5> in <module>()
----> 1 from utils import show_test_cases, test_case_checker, perform_computation

ImportError: cannot import name 'show_test_cases'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you post link to the library repository?

Comment: I also have the same problem with a Cryptohack coding challenge I am working on. The line of code is 'from utils import listener # this is cryptohack's server-side module and not part of python'